# How can I remove the gap between friday and monday candles in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I have slightly modified the original sample from matplotlib (finance_work2.py) to plot a Candlestick graph instead of a Line graph.
What I'd like to know is how can I remove the gap between friday and monday candles ?

Any help will be appreciated.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.finance as finance
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
from matplotlib.dates import date2num


startdate = datetime.date(2013,5,1)
today = enddate = datetime.date.today()
ticker = 'SPY'

fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker, startdate, enddate)
# a numpy record array with fields: date, open, high, low, close, volume, adj_close)

r = mlab.csv2rec(fh); fh.close()
r.sort()


### plot graph divisions
plt.rc('axes', grid=True)
plt.rc('grid', color='0.75', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
textsize = 9
left, width = 0.1, 0.8
rect1 = [left, 0.3, width, 0.4]
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
axescolor  = '#f6f6f6'
ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect1, axisbg=axescolor)


### plot the price
prices = r.adj_close
dx = r.adj_close - r.close
low = r.low + dx
high = r.high + dx
deltas = np.zeros_like(prices)
deltas[1:] = np.diff(prices)
up = deltas>0

candlesticks = zip(date2num(r['date']),r['open'],r['close'],r['high'],r['low'],r['volume'])
candlestick(ax1, candlesticks,width=1,colorup='g', colordown='r')

plt.show()
```

i've tried with this modification but I get an error I don't understand:

```
weekday_quotes = [tuple([i]+list(quote[1:])) for i,quote in enumerate(candlesticks)]
candlestick(ax2, weekday_quotes,width=1,colorup='g', colordown='r')
```

There is another question on this site regarding the same problem, but the code is NOT based on numpy arrays and I suspect that's why the workaround is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Christian, can you reduce the amount of code to just that required to understand the problem? Currently this is producing over 7 plots so it's not obvious where the problem lies or which part of the code needs to be considered.

Comment: As requested, I've posted a simplified example. Thanks for your time Greg.

Comment: Using a striped down version your modification removes the weekends from the data as expected. However with all the other things your plotting, if you remove the weekends from just the candlesticks it will error as it no longer shares the same axes as the other objects. So do you need to remove the weekends from all objects?

Comment: That's the problem with striped examples :-) I'm afraid I do need to remove weekends from all objects... Would you like me to post the entire code again ? I'm trying to apply the workaround right after downloading the data but so far I haven't advanced too much. Thanks !!